# Additive basis for polynomials of degree exactly $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

I introduce some work I have done below, and the questions are at the end.

For some $n>1$ fixed, let $Q_n$ be the set (not vector space) of polynomials with integer coefficients of degree *exactly* $n$. Then, I claim the set:

$$B = \{(x-k)^n:k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

is an additive basis for $Q_n$, by which I mean that any element of $Q_n$ may be expressed as a finite linear combination (over $\mathbb{Q}$) of the elements of $B$.

Indeed, any element of $Q_n$ has $n+1$ degrees of freedom, and I claim that any set of $n+1$ distinct elements in $B$ is linearly independent. If:

$$S=\{(x-k_0)^n, ..., (x-k_{n})^n\}$$

($k_i \neq k_j, i \neq j$) is such a subset of $B$, then, the matrix of coefficients of $x$, after removing factors of (non-zero) binomial coefficients from each column, is:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & k_0 & \cdots & k_0^{n}\\
1 & k_1 & & k_1^n\\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & k_n & \cdots & k_n^n
\end{pmatrix}

i.e. a square Vandermonde matrix, which is invertible.

---

**Questions**

1. Is the reasoning above correct? If not, is it nevertheless true that $B$ forms an additive basis for $Q_n$ as claimed?
2. Given that $B$ is an additive basis, is there a convenient way to express an element of $Q_n$ as a finite linear combination of elements of $B$? Is there any way to perhaps introduce an inner product or do some combinatorial wizardry?

Although this question seems to be in the field of linear algebra, I hope to use an answer to (2) to help solve certain ODEs.

Comment: Every element of $Q_n$ has $n+1$ degrees of freedom rather than $n$, but your otherwise correct argument can easily incorporate that change.

Comment: @GregMartin Oh, right; I was looking at the basis elements which are all monic. The discrepancy did seem strange. Thanks, I'll fix this.

Comment: As for the second question, I would take $n=4$ say and symbolically calculate the inverse of the coefficient matrix (with the binomial coefficients), looking for a pattern to generalize.

Comment: @GregMartin Since I can pick any set $k_0, ..., k_n$, any suggestions as to which values might be easiest to work with, given a particular polynomial?

Comment: Rather than looking only at $Q_n$, it's better to consider the vector space of polynomials of degree $\le n$.  Then you have a basis in the usual sense, and the standard techniques apply.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I agree; however, I haven't really studied $P_n$ either. Thus, I was hoping someone could fill that in for me.